# Does Filipino citizen with Slovenian residence need a UK transit visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino citizen living in Slovenia and I am a holder of a residence card as a family member of Slovenian citizen. With that card, I can travel with my Slovenian wife to the Canary Islands?

Our flight is from Ljubljana with transit in London Heathrow Airport, where we have to collect and recheck our luggage. Do we need a transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

1. "With that card, I can travel with my Slovenian wife to the Canary Islands?"

[**Yes you can**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=si&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=ES&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Slovenia for a maximum stay of 90 days [in a 180-day period].

Doesn't matter if it was issued on the basis of a family relation.

2. "Our flight is from Ljubljana with transit in London Heathrow Airport, where we have to collect and recheck our luggage. Do we need a transit visa?"

**[No, thanks to your Slovene residence card (for family members) you can stay in the UK together with your wife for as long as you want](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=si&PASSTYPES=PASS&TR=GB&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)**

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a "Family Member"
>   Residence Card marked "Permanent Residence Card of a Family
>   Member of a Union Citizen  or  Residence Card of a Family
>   Member of a Union Citizen  **issued by Slovenia to family
>   members of an EEA national** or national of
>   Switzerland **if traveling with** or traveling to join **the EEA
>   national** or national of Switzerland.

So just present your passport and residence card to Uk immigration